# NFS mounts with non-matching UIDs/ usernames

Tags: mount, nfs, automounting

There's a Linux machine where files are owned by a user named "lab" with a UID of 1000 (on the system).
There's another Linux machine where files are owned by a user named "user" with a UID of 500 (on the system).

How do I make a NFS mount so the files that are owned by "lab"/UID-1000 on the server are seen as owned by "user"/UID-500 on the client?

I can do this using a SSHFS mount, or even a CIFS mount, but SSHFS/CIFS breaks in other ways that I would rather not have to deal with.

Does NFS not support this use case atall?

Comment: Yes, assuming both machines support NFSv4. This is discussed briefly in the [Linux home server howto](http://www.brennan.id.au/19-Network_File_System.html). It can also be done with NFSv2 or NFSv3 if you use the [kernel-based NFS server](http://www.kernelcrash.com/blog/nfs-uidgid-mapping/2007/09/10/).

Answer (score 3):

I used the kernel-based NFS server [following this article](http://www.kernelcrash.com/blog/nfs-uidgid-mapping/2007/09/10/), the following worked:

On the server,
I used the following options:

```
rw,sync,no_acl,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000
```

On the client, I used the following options:

```
-o rw,sync,vers=3,hard,intr,nolock,tcp,noac
```

and I have write permissions, even though UID/GID/Username don't match!

Comment: do we have any idea why these settings work? what do they all mean?